# I was told whenever we have equi-spaced equi-potential planes, field must be constant. I seek the proof of this statement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, gauss-law

[image]

Y-axis vertical line and the other is X-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have presented a better pic for the question. I will provide a crude explanation. To prove it, one should remember, that :
$$
E = -\nabla \phi
$$
And the equipotential surfaces $\phi = $ const are orthogonal to the lines of $E$. These surfaces are all parallel, therefore, the vector $E$ points in the same direction at every point. The difference of potentials between every two points 1 and 2 is:
$$
\phi(2) - \phi(1) = - \int \limits_1^{2} \vec{E} \cdot d \vec{x} 
$$
Because the planes are located equi-spaced, taking, for example, infinitesimal distance between 1 and 2, one gets that for the displacement on the same fixed amount $dx$ along the direction of $E$, the potential changes for the same value $d \phi$. Therefore, $E$ is also constant, when moving along the direction of $\vec{E}$.

Comment: Why going through all that trouble? Equi-spaced equipment-potential planes simply means in one-dimension $d\phi/dx =const$. Hence, in higher dimensions this becomes $\nabla \phi = const$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will ensure my doubts are made clearer to the viewers the next time I post something.